# grep word from column and remove row

Tags: shell, unix

I want to `grep` a word from particular column from a file. Then remove those rows put all remaining rows into another file.
could anyone please help me on shell command to get following output?

I have a file with this format:

```
1234     8976     897561234   1234  678901234
5678     5678     123456789   4567  123456790
1234     1234     087664566   4567  678990000
1223     6586     212134344   8906  123456789
```

I want to grep word "1234" in the second column alone and removed those rows alone and put remaining rows in another file. So output should be in this format:

```
1234     8976     897561234   1234  678901234
5678     5678     123456789   4567  123456790
1223     6586     212134344   8906  123456789
```

The out should be with 3 rows except 3 row out of 4 rows.

```
while read value ;do
  grep -v  ${value:0:10} /tmp/lakshmi.txt > /tmp/output.txt
  cp /tmp/output.txt /tmp/no_post1.txt
done < /tmp/priya.txt
```

Could you please help me to modify this script?

Comment: Priya.txt file will be having 1234

Comment: how do you filter that you want to grep "1234" in second column only? Do you have any pattern or you want to do it just this once? Is it always going to be second column?

Comment: I assumed you want to delete several records from lakshmi.txt, with the keys that you want to remove given in priya.txt. Can you confirm this (for other answers)?

Comment: Ignoring the grep question your script has another problem: In each loop the result of the previous loop will be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` for this, if that's good for you:

```
awk '$2==1234' <file-name>
```

`$2` represents second column and it will return the line:

```
1234     1234     087664566   4567  678990000
```

Then you can use `sed`, `grep -v` or even `awk` for further process, either delete this line from current file, or print only the lines that do not match to another file. `awk` will be much easier and powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regular expression.

```
egrep -v "^[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+1234[[:space:]]+.*$"
```

Not sure what your intention is, but my best guess is that you want to do the following.

```
while read value ;do
  egrep -v "^[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+${value:0:10}[[:space:]]+.*$" /tmp/lakshmi.txt > /tmp/output.txt
  cp /tmp/output.txt /tmp/no_post1.txt
done < /tmp/priya.txt
```

Comment: It certainly works, but it feels clumsy compared with using `awk`.  You could use: `egrep -v '^[[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){3}1234[[:space:]]'` to pick up the value 1234 in column 4.  The `{3}` repeats the 'column, space-after-column' item 3 times, then the `1234` and a space afterwards picks up the value 1234 in column 4.

Comment: Sure, `awk` may be a better choice. OP seemed interested in a `grep` based solution.

Answer (score 0):

For columnar data, `awk` is often the best tool to use.

Superficially, if your input data is in `priya.txt` and you want the output in `lakshmi.txt`, then this would do the job:

```
awk '$2==1234 { next } { print }' priya.txt > lakshmi.txt
```

The first pattern detects `1234` (and also 01234 and 0001234) in column 2 and executes a `next` which skips the rest of the script.  The rest of the script prints the input data; people often use `1` in place of `{ print }`, which achieves the same effect less verbosely (or less clearly).

If you want the line(s) with `1234` in another file (`filtered.out`, say), then you'd use:

```
awk '$2==1234 { print > "filtered.out"; next } { print }' priya.txt > lakshmi.txt
```

If the column must be exactly `1234` rather than just numerically equal to `1234`, then you would use a regx match instead:

```
awk '$2 ~ /^1234$/ { next } { print }' priya.txt > lakshmi.txt
```

The great thing about `awk` is that it splits the data into fields automatically, and that usually makes it easy to process columnar data with `awk`. You can also use Perl or Python or other similar scripting languages to do much the same job.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the record layout exactly. When an empty first field is replaced by 4 spaces, the clever solutions will fail. Can a field have a space inside?
When your fields have fixed offsets, you might want to check the offset:

```
grep -v "^.\{9\}1234"
```

When /tmp/priya.txt has more than 1 line, your while loop becomes ugly:

```
cp /tmp/lakshmi.txt /tmp/output.txt
while read value ;do
  grep -v "^.\{9\}${value}" /tmp/output.txt > /tmp/output2.txt
  mv /tmp/output2.txt /tmp/output.txt
done < /tmp/priya.txt
```

You can also use the -f option of grep:

```
echo "1234     8976     897561234   1234  678901234
5678     5678     123456789   4567  123456790
1234     1234     087664566   4567  678990000
1223     6586     212134344   8906  123456789" |grep -vf <(sed 's/^/^.\\{9\\}/' /tmp/priya.txt )
```

or in your case

```
grep -vf <(sed 's/^/^.\\{9\\}/' /tmp/priya.txt ) /tmp/lakshmi.txt
```